# Throughout in Spanish

Tags: traducción

I tried translating "throughout the interview" into Spanish and Google returned three translations:

> A lo largo de la entrevista.
>
> A lo largo la entrevista.
>
> Largo la entrevista.
>
> Lo largo la entrevista.
>
> Largo de la entrevista.

What's the difference? Which one of the above would be the most natural way to convey the meaning in regular conversations and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the first is correct:

> **A lo largo de** la entrevista.

Another option would be:

> **Durante** la entrevista.

Comment: *Durante* sounds nicer.

Comment: "_Durante_ la entrevista" suggests that something took place at some point during the interview, not all the time throughout. I'd rather add _toda_: _"Durante TODA la entrevista"_